# crop object from a masked and RGB image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to crop an object(Here, it is chair) from an RGB Image. I have the masked image also. Here, I have given [RGB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AWb7.jpg) and [Object mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7BTb.jpg). The chair is now in white colour. My query is how can I crop this chair form RGB image using OpenCV and object mask. I am thinking in a way---

1. At first, segment the object mask image and extract the white coloured chair and make the remaining part black.
2. Draw a rectangular shape around the white portion and get the coordinates of the rectangular.
3. Coordinates obtained from number 2 pass to the RGB image and crop it using that region.

Is there any other easy way to do it? Or, if my approach is OK then, please suggest me how can I do the segmentation and make a rectangular around the white object.

Comment: Depends on whether chair is still on the same position - otherwise you would have to detect them using some detector trained on chairs, or annotate chairs manually.

Comment: I have given some [example_pic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eJFvs2OMNyKlHFUzazgO6L6p9sPXvDYU) here. Can you please take a look and suggest me which approach I have to take?

Comment: Area of synthetic datasets is kind of tricky, I'm also training detector (YOLOv3) on synthetic dataset of Traffic signs [as you can see here](https://github.com/kocica/TrainingDatasetGenerator/blob/master/results/v5/giveway1.jpg). But since I'm placing the signs into images, i know exactly where they are. Isnt it possible to extract also position from Unreal engine ? If you had just one wrongly annotated chair - it could destroy whole learning process, so I'm afraid i can't help you further :/

Comment: @FilipKočica I have edited my question. I think now it is more specific. I have made the masked image.  Can you please take a look at my question and give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. At first, converted to hsv and then marked the bouded box with the help of contour function of OpenCV the task has done. Here, I am giving the [Github link](https://github.com/atifkarim/unreal_cv_image_manipulation/tree/master/unreal_cv_image_processing_for_ML/object_subtraction_for_UE4) .